# How to Allow user to enter 'A' alphabet once?

Tags: android

It's a Hangman game, I want the user only can enter like 'A' once, then the second time he/she enter 'A' it will come out a Toast. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
     String letter = enterletter.getText().toString();
            char letterChar = letter.charAt(0);
            boolean check = false;
            enterletter.setText("");
            char array[] = new char[120];
            array[letterChar]++;

            if(array[letterChar] > 1){ //Here the codes not working
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You already enter this letter before!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                for (int i = 0; i < currWord.length(); i++) {
                    if (Character.toUpperCase(currWord.charAt(i)) == Character.toUpperCase(letterChar)) {
                        check = true;
                        charViews[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        numCorr++;

                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
char array[] = new char[120];
array[letterChar]++;
```

You are creating a new array that is initialized to all zeros and then increment the count for the character. So it will always be 1.

You need to allocate the array just once at a more global place. It is also somewhat misleading that the type is `char[]`. This works because a `char` is just an unsigned 16 bit number and what you really want is an integer count not a char.

Answer (score 1):

User only can enter like 'A' once solution is You can use if you want to set it by programming and without checking any condition

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
int maxLength = 1;    
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
```

and if you want by xml you can just use these two lines in your EditText limit and for Alphabet only.

```
android:maxLength="1"
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

no need to do more work, Just add all character in one string with the comma(,) separated and then after entering new character check it.
like bellow.

```
String allCharacters="";
    /**
     * Call this method where from entering character like editBox OnTextChange 
     */
    private void addCharacter(String charNew){
        if(allCharacters.trim().length()>0 && allCharacters.contains(","+charNew)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You already enter this letter before!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            allCharacters=allCharacters+","+charNew;
        }
    }
```